# how to transfer song files inside the same iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, music, music.app

i downloaded a song via music free download app and wanted to know how can i move this song from this app to the iphone5 music app where is usually stored our music from Itune ??? please can someone help me

Answer (score 1):

When your iPhone is not jailbreaked it is not possible.

When you have an jailbroken iPhone, it is possible to move files in your iPhone with iFile. The music in iTunes on your iPhone is stored within several maps so I do not know if it works when simple moving the music files.